# Two Image Views Get added to the scrollView which I add using objects library?

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode4.5

In my application I am using the ScrollView to show the list of data(by adding each view for each entry in the list), when an new entry is added to the data list I add a new view as subView to the scrollView,I use subViews count to position the newly added view and there I came across an issue that my scrollView has two imageViews.

I checked it in the -viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"subvs %@",[sampleScroll subviews]);
}
```

here is my console window

```
subvs (
    "<UIImageView: 0x72b9610; frame = (233 121; 7 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; animations = { contentsCenter=<CABasicAnimation: 0x72dd8b0>; position=<CABasicAnimation: 0x72e2520>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x72b96b0>>",
    "<UIImageView: 0x72e2ae0; frame = (233 121; 7 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; animations = { contentsCenter=<CABasicAnimation: 0x72b7c50>; position=<CABasicAnimation: 0x72b7ce0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x72e2b80>>"
)
```

Edit:-I've added the scrollView by drag and drop in xib

Comment: Where you adding ? and what's `objects libray` ?

Comment: @BuntyMadan i'am adding it in xib

Comment: means when new entry found you need to add a new view on the `UIScrollView` ?

Comment: @BuntyMadan yes, but the problem is two imageView that are get added as default

Comment: so you can add `UIImageView` diagrammatically. as you added two first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the horizontal and vertical scroll indicators(which are UIImageviews by default) which are initialized with the scrollview

if you don't want then you can remove them like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"subvs %@",[sampleScroll subviews]);

    for(UIView *view in sampleScroll.subviews){
        [view removeFromSuperview];
   }

}
```